# Cross Link HTML5 Apps on SAP Cloud Platform

Tags: html, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

What is the best way to link to other Apps in SAP Hana Cloud Platform without using Fiori Launchpad.

these 3 things we have tried:

1. Hard coded URLs (uncool and dirty)
2. via Destination? (doesn´t work - get some auth errors )
3. via neo-app.json configurred application resource (doesn´t work, because the destinations are missing in the linked app)

Comment: Have you seen this blog series? https://blogs.sap.com/2017/10/23/demystifying-the-art-of-component-reuse-in-sapui5/

Comment: Yes i have read it and we also use it for shared libraries. But for crosslinking between apps it will not work. Because the scope of the linked app ist the scope of the source app which is wrong for e.g. destination resolving...

Comment: And intent based navigation is out of the question? I have no other suggestions...

Comment: @Jorg I think for the future this is the only solution. For now we build us an XSJS endpoint which is called CrosssApplicationTargets.xsjs and returns us the corresponding URLs for each Application we want to link between. We have to configure it on serverside which is fine for now.

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more detailed what you would like to do?

Comment: We have ca. 10 HTML5 Apps on SCP. We want to cross link between this Apps  without using Fiori Launchpad. Because we have multiple subaccounts which are used for staging, integration etc. the URL´s changing for each subaccount level. We try to find a solution how to navigate to apps on subaccount level without adapting the URLs after each deployment.